# how do I get the values retrieved from objectdatasource and display them in a formview's updatetemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, formview

I want that the dropdownlist that is contained in the updatetemplate have the selectedindex of the value returned from the database?

Comment: Have you tried anything or at least read a tutorial? A `FormView` has no `UpdateTemplate`, maybe you mean `EditTemplate`.

Comment: You are right it is edittemplate. I have searched all day, google and even on my book of asp.net.

Comment: Currently this is not a question that can be answered. Can you describe what you have tried and what went wrong? Yould should also include all relevant code, aspx and codebehind.

Comment: first i realized that there's no way of doing this (get a int value from the database and set as the selectedindex of a dropdownlist within an "edittemplate" without code behind. So my question is "what event do I have to handle to get this task done". I tried to check the eventargs of all events but I didn't find any relevant properties.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution

It is property that doesn't appear on intellisense called SelectedValue on design view

the code goes like this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMarca"  SelectedValue='<%# Bind("marcaid") %>'    runat="server"   DataValueField=""    >
```